# Key-value simplest embeddable DB for Java app (or someting else)

Tags: java, database, key-value

I need DB for my Java desktop app. Example data structure that i want to put into it:

`(Name) (Hash)
 aaa   23s92j39
 bbb   d309oc08`

It`s going to be RO (i download it from the Internet, search by name and get hashes). Do I really need DB for that purpose? Or I should use JSON/MessagePack/.txt file or something else? My goal is to find hash by name very quickly.

Comment: P.S. I can't get hash directly by applying some function to name (it's not name hash, it's BitTorrent hash)

Comment: If this is your personal project, then file system is fine.

Comment: *Do I really need DB for that purpose?* Only if you'd like to not reinvent the wheel and instead use some tested and optimized library which does queries for you. In that case, SQLite could be an option: you get the power of SQL without an actual server. Of course slower, but still optimized and easy to use (and probably better than writing and debugging some searching algorithm from scratch).

Comment: But I don't need all the power of SQL, I need just blazing fast key-value store.

Comment: Faraz, what is file system? .txt's? But aren't DBs faster?

Comment: @hyperapps19 Use two columns, one as primary key and the other as "value". Bit of an antipattern for SQL but it would work in your scenario.

Comment: *"But aren't DBs faster?"* How bigs you're dataset? Millions of rows?  What type of operations are you intending to do on the dataset? Searching/grouping/filtering/etc.  Answer test and you'll get a better idea of whether you need a DB or not

Comment: Take a look at RocksDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chronicle Map (https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map). It's NoSQL and key-value.